# xamarin emulator in visual studio 2017 not working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have been reading many accounts of the difficulties of working with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017, but there is a problem that has not been covered by any of them.  I need some insights and assistance.  I sent an e-mail to vs@xamarin.com, but never received a reply.

The problem exists that the emulator will launch, but the android app will not load.  I let my machine run all weekend just to see if 72 hours would allow the app to load.  It did not load.  On one rare occasion, the app did load, but once it loaded, it would not work again in the same emulator.

I also tried connecting my android 7.1 phone to the emulator system, but the phone would never show up.  I tried with API 23 and API 25 for the phone and the emulators.  The crazy thing I see in the log is that it is using preview for API 26.  I could not find the configuration where it using the configuration for API 26 anywhere.  I searched my entire hard drive for 26.0.0 and it was no where to be found.  This seems to be the only issue that I run in to.

My configuration is as follows.

- Development laptop Windows 10 Pro with the latest updates 64-bit OS.
- HP Laptop with 16 GB memory and 512 GB SSD card.  There is plenty of 
  available memory and hard disk space.
- Visual Studio - 15.2 (26430.16) 32-bit version
- .net - 4.7.02046 xamarin - 4.5.0486
- xamarin.android.sdk - 7.3.1.2

If you need additional information, let me know.

Comment: are you using correct version of JVM? try using JVM that came with the Visual Studio default installation.

Comment: What emulator are you using and what ABI? Your phone, do you have developer mode enabled and USB debugging enabled and the appropriate drivers installed?

Comment: Are you using an x86 android emulator? Do you have the haxm drivers installed?

Comment: can you share the log?

Comment: You are most likely using a slow `ARMEABI` emulator which is not suitable for development. It is recommended to use an `x86` emulator accelerated with HAXM. If you can't use that, use the Visual Studio Emulator for Android if you need hyper-v compatibility. Otherwise, a real device is going to be your best experience.

Comment: using the correct JVM 1.8.

Comment: developer mode was enabled on the phone and connect via usb to the computer.  Not sure what you mean by appropriate drivers.  Are these on the phone or the computer?

Comment: HAXM drivers are installed.  Using x86 emulator.

Comment: Ganesh, what log are you referring to and where would it reside in all probability?  I have many logs for many things.  VS 2017 and Xamarin were installed right out of the box in the standard libraries.

Comment: I believe I am using the x86 emulator and not the ARMABI emulator.

Comment: fixed the zipalign to point to 25.0.3

Comment: This is what shows up in the output window when trying to run a deploy.  Deployment is for a 5.3" phone that I create in AVD with API 7.1 (25)

1>Starting deploy LG-M257 ...
1>Starting emulator LG-M257 ...
1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd LG-M257 -prop monodroid.avdname=LG-M257
1>Hax is enabled
1>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
1>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
1>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
1>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
1>Your emulator is out of date

Comment: continuation of the comment

Comment: continuation of the comment

>EasyTechAndroid -> c:\workspaces\EAppsInXamarin\EasyTechAndroid\bin\Release\EasyTechAndroid.dll
1>  Processing: obj\Release\res\layout\start.xml
1>  Processing: obj\Release\res\values\strings.xml
1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\apeet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\apeet\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"

Comment: I finally found the problem after digging about 12 levels deep into some stack overflow issues.  I will recap it here.

Comment: when using the xamarin android emulator, not the visual studio emulator for android, you must do the following in order for you app to push to the emulator.

clean and build the project in the normal fashion.
start the emulator from tools>>android>>android emulator manager
select the emulator you want and click the start button out to the right in the window.
Once the emulator is running, then at the top of visual studio, select the same emulator (AVD) and hit run.  

The screen will flash a number of times and then the app is on the emulator.  It all works.

Comment: that is wierd.  i never had to do anything but press the "play" button to debug.  I am glad you got it working